# Construct a dynamic HTML content using Database values

Tags: python, html, python-3.x, postgresql

I want to create a dynamic HTML page with the values from the PostgresQL database applied in necessary position of the HTML template.

The below image is a part of HTML page, i want that areas to be filled from the values from the database,Is there a way to do that? or is there any other better way to do that.

Im using Python and PostgreSQL database.

Thanks in Advance

```
  import psycopg2
  import jinja2
  from collections import namedtuple
  TEMPLATE="""
     <!DOCTYPE html>
       <html><head><title>Jinja Template Example</title>
       <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial- 
  scale=1.0">
       <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" 
   rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
       <style type="text/css">
       .container {max-width: 500px;padding-top: 100px;}</style></head>
       <body>
        <div class="container">
         <p>My string: {{my_string}}</p>
         <p>Value from the list:</p>
         <p>Loop through the list:</p>
         <p style="line-height: 14px; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;"> Database Value </p><br>
         <p style="line-height: 14px;font-weight:Bold; text-align: center; font-size: 12px; margin: 0;">Database value</p>

         <ul>
           {% for row in test_records %}
           <li>{{ test_records.column1 }}</li>
           {% endfor %}
         </ul>
        </div>
          <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"> 
          </script>
          <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstr

          ap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
          </body>
      </html>
      """
  def dB_Fetch():
  try:
   connection = psycopg2.connect(user="sandeep",
                                  password="postgres",
                                  host="127.0.0.1",
                                  port="5432",
                                  database="postgres")
   cursor = connection.cursor()
   postgreSQL_select_Query = "select * from test"
   cursor.execute(postgreSQL_select_Query)
   print("Selecting rows from test table using cursor.fetchall")
   test_records = cursor.fetchall()
   a = list();
   print("Print each row and it's columns values")
   for row in test_records:
       a.append(test_records);
       #print("column1 = ", row[0] )
       #print("column2 = ", row[1])
       print(a[0])

   env = jinja2.Environment()
   template = env.from_string(TEMPLATE)
   row_tuple = namedtuple("Row", [col[0] for col in cursor.description])
   result = template.render(rows=[row_tuple(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()])
   print (TEMPLATE)
   print (result)  

 except (Exception, psycopg2.Error) as error:
     print ("Error while fetching data from PostgreSQL", error)
 finally:
     if(connection):
         cursor.close()
         connection.close()
         print("PostgreSQL connection is closed")
   if __name__ == '__main__':
    dB_Fetch()
    enter code here
```

I'm getting an error in this code can you please show me?
[image]

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Best way to approach this would be to read the data using [Psycopg](http://initd.org/psycopg/docs/), and then some templating engine - [jinja2](http://jinja.pocoo.org), for instance - to generate the HTML given data from the database.

**Update**:

A sketch of a solution might look like this (untested).

```py
import psycopg2
import jinja2
from collections import namedtuple

TEMPLATE="""
<html><head></head><body>
<ul>
{% for row in rows %}
  <li>{{ row.column1 }}, {{ row.column2 }}</li>
{% endfor %}
</ul>
</body></html>
"""

env = jinja2.Environment()
template = env.from_string(TEMPLATE)

with psycopg2.connect("dbname=test user=postgres") as conn:
    with conn.cursor() as curs:
        curs.execute("SELECT column1, column2 FROM test;")
        row_tuple = namedtuple("Row", [col[0] for col in curs.description])
        print(template.render(rows=[row_tuple(row) for row in curs.fetchall()]))
```

Comment: I think you should show some example to beginners for good understanding. :)

Comment: Yes that isn't before my comment.

Comment: @Hafza, Can you show me where i'm getting the error in the above code?

Comment: What is the error you are getting?

Comment: The values from the database is not rendered to the HTML.

Comment: I have added the part of HTML where i want to update the database value, but when i tried the values are not displayed in the output HTML?Any suggestions or anything to point out?

Comment: Can you show us the actual code you're running? Possibly as another question?

Comment: You seem to be printing the template, rather than the output of the render function.

Comment: You've also run `cursor.fetchall()` twice.

Comment: cursor.fetchall() twice i just checked whether the DB connectivity was working,That is not the issue and i have modified the script like this,              
   result = template.render(rows=[row_tuple(row) for row in cursor.fetchall()])
   print (TEMPLATE)
   print (result), but the DB values is not in the rendered HTML

Comment: Well, the 1st invocation will consume all the records, leaving none for the 2nd invocation, so I think it is an issue. But also, you are printing your template, not the output from `render()`.

Comment: OK, now what are you seeing?

Comment: I have modified the script.Can you please check on that. I have assigned the render(=) result to a variable and print that,which i corrected in the above code.

Comment: This is the output now(Values are not being updated in the output HTML) .     ,<div class="container">
         <p>My string: </p>
         <p>Value from the list:</p>
         <p>Loop through the list:</p>
         <ul>
           
         </ul>
        </div>

Comment: You are *still* calling `cursor.fetchall()` twice, so I expect you're seeing no rows in the rendered version, right?

Comment: Remove the 1st `cursor.fetchall()` and the `test_records` stuff, and see what you get.

Comment: Can you show me how i can modify it and get the values?

Comment: HeyGot it :) Thanks brunn for the support :)

Comment: Good. Do go ahead and accept the answer, then!

Comment: I think this answer is OK - the conversation was just helping you implement your version of it!

Comment: Thanks a lot brunns for your assistance :)

Answer (score 0):

Code style must be like below. You can search DB application with jinja2. 
Only changes, you give your data from list after execution of database query.

It's a simple example for beginners:

```
    <!DOCTYPE html>
<html>
  <head>
    <title>Flask Template Example</title>
    <meta name="viewport" content="width=device-width, initial-scale=1.0">
    <link href="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/css/bootstrap.min.css" rel="stylesheet" media="screen">
    <style type="text/css">
      .container {
        max-width: 500px;
        padding-top: 100px;
      }
    </style>
  </head>
  <body>
    <div class="container">
      <p>My string: {{my_string}}</p>
      <p>Value from the list: {{my_list[3]}}</p>
      <p>Loop through the list:</p>
      <ul>
        {% for n in my_list %}
        <li>{{n}}</li>
        {% endfor %}
      </ul>
    </div>
    <script src="http://code.jquery.com/jquery-1.10.2.min.js"></script>
    <script src="http://netdna.bootstrapcdn.com/bootstrap/3.0.0/js/bootstrap.min.js"></script>
  </body>
</html>
```